# Run cucumber by tag or run all tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am having hard time with running cucumber. I want to run either all scenarios if tags are not passed as CLI argument or certain scenarios according to passed tags as CLI argument.
Here is my config file:

```js
module.exports = {
  default: {
    tags: '@run or ""',
    formatOptions: {
      snippetInterface: 'async-await'
    },
    paths: [
      'src/features/'
    ],
    dryRun: false,
    require: [
      'src/step_definitions/**/*.ts',
      'hooks.ts'
    ],
    requireModule: [
      'ts-node/register'
    ],
    format: [
      'json:test-results/json-report.json',
      'progress'
    ],
    parallel: process.env.CI ? 10 : 1
  }
}
```

here is the script to run tests:

```json
"test": "cucumber-js --config=configs/cucumber.cjs || true"
```

If I pass @run tag scenarios with that tag run or no tests run. If I remove tag property from the config no matter what tag I pass all tests are being run. For example, I have this scenario:

```
@api
Scenario: Name of the scenario
// Steps
```

config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  default: {
    formatOptions: {
      snippetInterface: 'async-await'
    },
    paths: [
      'src/features/'
    ],
    dryRun: false,
    require: [
      'src/step_definitions/**/*.ts',
      'hooks.ts'
    ],
    requireModule: [
      'ts-node/register'
    ],
    format: [
      'json:test-results/json-report.json',
      'progress'
    ],
    parallel: process.env.CI ? 10 : 1
  }
}
```

Command in terminal:

```bash
npm run test --tags="@api"
```

This command is running all tests. How can I make it to run tests with specific tag if that tag is passed CLI argument, or run all tests?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: where are you accepting `--tags` in your npm script?Try updating your script something like: `"test": "cucumber-js --config=configs/cucumber.cjs --tags \"@run or \"\"\""` and then run your script like: `npm run test -- --tags="@api"`. I'm assuming this should work.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around the code I found the solution:
updated config:

```js
module.exports = {
  default: {
// removed tags property
    formatOptions: {
      snippetInterface: 'async-await'
    },
    paths: [
      'src/features/'
    ],
    dryRun: false,
    require: [
      'src/step_definitions/**/*.ts',
      'hooks.ts'
    ],
    requireModule: [
      'ts-node/register'
    ],
    format: [
      'json:test-results/json-report.json',
      'progress'
    ],
    parallel: process.env.CI ? 10 : 1
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": ""cucumber-js --config=configs/cucumber.cjs"
}
```

test run command:

```
npm run test -- --tags "@TAG_NAME" || true
```

Comment: it is not working. still its picking all the scenarios

Comment: I need to see your config file before saying something.